# Coq Error: There are pending proofs

Tags: coq

I implemented the following `Coq` program following example code from [this](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Basics.html#lab18) online book.

```
Inductive day : Type :=
  | monday : day
  | tuesday : day
  | wednesday : day
  | thursday : day
  | friday : day
  | saturday : day
  | sunday : day.

Definition next_weekday (d:day) : day :=
  match d with
  | monday => tuesday
  | tuesday => wednesday
  | wednesday => thursday
  | thursday => friday
  | friday => monday
  | saturday => monday
  | sunday => monday
  end.

Example test_next_weekday:
  (next_weekday (next_weekday saturday)) =
tuesday.
```

I attempt to compile this file `error.v` by running `$ coqc error.v`, and get a `There are pending proofs` error.

```
$ coqc error.v
Error: There are pending proofs
make: *** [makefile:7: make] Error 1
```

**Why am I getting this error?**

Comment: Did you prove the statement that `(next_weekday (next_weekday saturday)) = tuesday`? Note that the reference you link to includes a proof: `Proof. simpl. reflexivity. Qed.`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson I added the proof and that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunate that Coq does not have a complete list of errors in the reference manual; I've reported [an issue for this on GitHub](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/6688).

The error message `Error: There are pending proofs` means "there are theorems that you have stated but not completed the proofs of.  Newer versions of Coq (perhaps only the development versions at this point) should name the pending theorems (see [this PR on GitHub](https://github.com/coq/coq/pull/755)).

The solution is to either give a proof of `test_next_weekday` (as suggested in the comments), to close the proof with `Admitted.`, or to abort the proof with `Abort.`.